# How to persist data injected into DataStore in JSData

Tags: jsdata

JSData [DS#inject](http://www.js-data.io/docs/dsinject) documentation states that:

> Injecting an item into the data store does not save it to the server.

There is a way to persist resources injected into DataStore?

Say, as example, that I modified multiple resources injecting them into DataStore, there is a way to persist all the modifications automatically?
What could be the best approach?

I am probably missing the point here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSData 2.x, you can save individual records by calling `DSSave` on the record itself, or by calling `DS#save` and passing the primary key of the record to be saved. See http://www.js-data.io/v2.8/docs/dssave and http://www.js-data.io/v2.8/docs/dsupdate

In JSData 3.x (still in beta), there is a batch update (`updateMany`) that can save multiple modified entities at once. See also: [Saving data](http://www.js-data.io/v3.0/docs/saving-data), [Mapper#update](http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/Mapper.html#update__anchor), [Record#save](http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/Record.html#save__anchor), [DataStore#updateMany](http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/DataStore.html#updateMany__anchor)